# Multiple asynchronous calls on webservice method in application fails with exception

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, web-services, wcf

i'm trying to create an application which connects to internet and consume `web services` for every of it's operation.As far as i'm concerned i'll like to use`async method` which i'm using already to get a collection of Contacts.I've realized that when i'm doing the same for groups (meaning getting groups async) i'm having errors in the calls , but when using normal call there ins't.So i did some research online and find that a lot of people has the same problem.
Some of them are asked to use `WCF` (for which i don't know jack).I'll like to know if there is another way to overcome this. if not can somebody point me to reliable resource online and help me get through it? thanks for reading and helping
 here is my code:

```
 public partial class main : Window
{
    //...
    private static vmcSession session;
    private MyService service = new MyService();
    private contactInfo[] loadedcontact;
    //....

    public main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //service.addContactCompleted +=new addContactCompletedEventHandler(addContactCompleted);
        service.getContactsCompleted += new getContactsCompletedEventHandler(getContactsCompleted);
        service.getGroupsCompleted += new getGroupsCompletedEventHandler(getGroupsCompleted);
        fillContents();
    }

    private void getGroupsCompleted(object sender, getGroupsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            groupListBox.ItemsSource = e.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }

    private void getContactsCompleted(object sender, getContactsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            loadedcontact = e.Result;
            contactListBox.ItemsSource = loadedcontact;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void addContactCompleted(object sender, addContactCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void fillContents()
    {
        displayUserInformation();
        loadContacts();
        service.getGroupsAsync(session.key, null);
        //groupListBox.ItemsSource = service.getGroups(session.key, null);
        cmbSenderIds.ItemsSource = service.getSenderIds(session.key, null);
        if (cmbSenderIds.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            cmbSenderIds.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        loadGrid();


    }


    public void loadContacts()
    {
        service.getContactsAsync(session.key, null);
    }



    public void displayUserInformation()
    {
        lblName.Content = session.user.firstName;
        lblEmail.Content = session.user.email;
        lblCreditValue.Content = Decimal.Ceiling(session.user.balance).ToString();

    }


    public void loadGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            hitoryGrid.ItemsSource = service.viewMessages(session.key, null).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }     

}
```

Comment: the InnerExeption Message was: `there was an error during asynchronous processing.Unique State object is required for multiple asynchronous simultaneous operation to be outstanding` 
thanks for the reply

Comment: Can you post some code? Are you calling SleepAsync?

Comment: Hi Henk i edited my question to have the code i'm using.and not I'm not calling SleepAsync. thanks for the reply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

solve it.there are 2 methods with async calls, one with additional parameter Unique ID.each of the call needed ID, so i pass new GUID to it and that's it.thanks for trying helping me

Comment: can you show your corrected code, how it got resolved?

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad, He's using the overloaded version of the method that takes an additional parameter (object userState). As value for this parameter, he is passing a unique value - Guid.NewGuid(). That would suffice the requirement for "Unique state object is required for multiple asynchronous simultaneous operations".