# Why does calling Async Web Service Method multiple times continuously only executes the method once

Tags: .net, web-services, asynchronous

I have an Web Service that I am trying to call multiple times using an async method. The method simply logs the call, no Exceptions are raised and it doesn't return anything.

However, only the first call is logged, the rest don't make it. If call the web method synchronously, or instantiate the web service proxy each time before, or slow down the calls, the calls works.

No fire walls are involved, no traffic leaves the machine (I've also tried hosting the service on another machine).

Can anyone explain why only the first async call succeeds and the rest don't? Also - the completed event is fired the correct number of times, which is very strange! I hooked up fiddler and only the first web service call leaves my machine.

Calling code (Runs web method once only):

```
    Dim svc As New wsLogThisService.LogThisService
    AddHandler svc.LogTestCompleted, AddressOf Completed

    For i As Integer = 1 To 100
        Dim request As New TestRequest
        request.LogLevel = LogLevelOptions.Err
        request.Counter = i.ToString

        svc.LogTestAsync(request)
    Next
```

Calling code (Works):

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To 100

        Dim svc As New wsLogThisService.LogThisService
        AddHandler svc.LogTestCompleted, AddressOf Completed

        Dim request As New TestRequest
        request.LogLevel = LogLevelOptions.Err
        request.Counter = i.ToString

        svc.LogTestAsync(request)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822779/problem-in-multiple-asynchronous-calls-on-webservice-method-in-wpf-application/) - you need to include a state object if you aren't instantiating the  service proxy each time.